# Jenkins Active Choices Reference Parameter not displaying returned results

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am using opensource **Jenkins 2.235.3** version on **Centos 7.7** machine with **Active Choices Plug-in Version 2.4**

The problem I am running into is very strange

I am using a groovy script to dynamically populate parameters and I am using Active Choices Reactive Parameter. In that plugin I have written a following groovy script

**Groovy Code:**

```
this.class.classLoader.addURL(new URL("file:///var/lib/jenkins/.groovy/grapes/org.yaml/snakeyaml/jars/snakeyaml-1.17.jar"))
def url = 'git@xxx.xxx.com:csd/deployment.git'
def envlist = ['/bin/bash', '-c', ' ssh-add  /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa_git; cd /var/lib/jenkins/services/; git archive --remote='+ url +' master inventory | tar xvf -' ].execute().
envlist.waitFor()
def yaml = Class.forName("org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml").newInstance()
def config = yaml.load(new FileReader("/var/lib/jenkins/services/inventory/${SERVICES}.yml"))
return config.all.children."${SERVICES}".children.keySet()
```

NOTE: **SERVICES** is another defined parameter

Whereas when I use Active choice reactive reference parameter with same code:

Same groovy code works and prints out the following result

```
"[functional, staging_stable, pilot_stable, prod_stable]"
```

When I use script console in manage jenkins, it runs fine and prints me the same result
Result:

```
[functional, staging_stable, pilot_stable, prod_stable]
```

When I check web console logs, I get

```
"Calling Java server code to update HTML elements... unochoice.js:154:17
Values returned from server: [[],[]] unochoice.js:157:21
```

How can I proceed with debugging, I want to only use Active Choices Reactive Parameter?
I have attached the screenshot to show how one is populated and one is not. Not enough to go through and debug this problem over the internet.
Can somebody please help?

Comment: Hello, have you solved this problem yet? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Just in case someone find this: `keySet()` returns `Set`, not a `list`. You should use `keySet().toList()`